# Hide tooltip on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

**We use tooltips, to display color names on a color picker.**

You can see the result here: [www.printnil.com](http://printnil.com/products/urkundenmappe?variant=1010444983)

Unfortunately the tooltips does not work really good.

The problem is, when you cursor is in the middle of the color picker and you move the cursor up to 
a further color, the tooltip doesn not disappear.

We need to find a solution to hide the tooltips, if you hover a new color or the the tooltip.

...
*We tried to move the tooltip upwards, so we get a little gap between the the color and the tooltip. But if you move the mouse faster you catch the transition effect.*

**Maybe some JavaScript?**

```
/** Color Swatches **/ 


.swatch { 
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.swatch .header {
  margin: 0.5em 0; 
}

.swatch input { 
  display:none;
}

.swatch label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
}

.swatch-element label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.swatch .swatch-element {
  width: 20%;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
  box-sizing: border-box;        
  float:left;
  -webkit-transform:translateZ(0); 
  -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; 
  position:relative;
}

.swatch input:checked + label {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}


.swatch input:checked + label:before {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  content: "\e607";
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
  padding: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;   
}

.swatch .tooltip {
  font: normal 12px sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
  background: #27282b;
  color:#fff;
  bottom:100%;
  padding:  10px;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  width:140%;
  left: -20%;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);
  -khtml-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  opacity:0;
  visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(10px);
  -o-transform: translateY(10px);
  transform: translateY(10px);
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;        
  z-index: 10000;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.swatch .tooltip:before {
  bottom:-20px;
  content:" ";
  display:block;
  height:20px;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
}

.swatch .tooltip:after {
  border-left:solid transparent 10px;
  border-right:solid transparent 10px;
  border-top:solid #27282b 10px;
  bottom:-9px;
  content:" ";
  height:0;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-13px;
  position:absolute;
  width:0;
}

.swatch .swatch-element:hover .tooltip {
  filter:alpha(opacity=100);
  -khtml-opacity:1;
  -moz-opacity:1;
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible;
  -webkit-transform:translateY(0px);
  -moz-transform:translateY(0px);
  -ms-transform:translateY(0px);
  -o-transform:translateY(0px);
  transform:translateY(0px);
}


/** Color Swatches **/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `pointer-events:none` to your `.swatch .tooltip`.

`.swatch .tooltip {
    ...;
    pointer-events : none
}`

I hope you are ok with [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

For IE browsers you can workaround lack of pointer-events with something like this:

`.swatch .tooltip:hover{display : none}`